# How can I deal with extensionless URLs locally?

Tags: html, url-rewriting

I've decided to use friendly/extensionless URLs on my IIS server. Now I'd like to try and find a way to easily edit and test extensionless code locally if possible. Sorry if this has been asked before but i didn't see any answers. I currently use VS Code and Sublime text, but am  certainly willing to change that if it will help. I also have access to my VPS server via remote desktop. Not sure how possible this is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You have a text editor. You have files. You have a web server. The web server maps URLs onto files. Nothing is stopping you using your editor to edit your files.

Comment: Yes, I can edit but would like to test via view in browser.

Comment: So type the URL into the browser.

Comment: Hang on: Is the answer you are looking for "Install IIS on your development environment and not just your live server"?

Comment: That has occurred to me, but not sure how well that would work. Have you (or anyone) tried that for this purpose? Did it work? And if so how easy was it to use? I of course realize I can always modify prior to uploading, but I've done that before with ASP I'd prefer to find a better way.